# Add image before "add to cart" button on woocomerce

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this snipet to add an image in every single product page

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_my_special_image', 40 );
  function add_my_special_image() {
      global $product;
    print '<img src="https://yoursite.com.au/wp-content/uploads/your-image-path.jpg" alt="your-image" class="my_image" />';
  }
```

The problem ( I know that may sound silly) is how to do it for every single product on my page.

I put this snippet on the functions.php, but I cant figured out how this works for every image (the image that I want to put in every page is different).

Someone can clarify that for me?
thanks!

Comment: Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to have a specific image show in that position for each product? Best option is to create a field for the product (using ACF is an easy way to do this) then instead of hardcoding the image you use the field from each product. So you would have something like:

```php
add_action ( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_my_special_image', 40 );

function add_my_special_image() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $image = get_field('product_image_field_name', $product_id);
    print '<img src="' . $image["url"] . '" alt="your-image" class="my_image" />';
}
```

If you use ACF, then see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/ for more on how to handle the image field.